# How to create multiple vsphere VMs of different name, different CPUs and memory requirement using terraform using for_each

Tags: terraform, hardware, vsphere

I have a scenario-

i have to provision multiple vsphere vms of different users with different cpus and memory requirement i am trying below code but its failing.

my terraform tfvars looks like -

```
  example_users = name1 {
  hardware = {cpus = 8
    memory = 10
}
},
 name2= {
   hardware = { cpus =9
   memory = 8
} 
},

and so-on
```

```
main.tf=

    for_each = var.example_users 
    cpus = each.value.hardware.cpus
    memory = each.value.harware.memory
```

can someone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terraform is looking for maps that are key:value pairs, so you could update your formatting a bit and likely have a functional config. I would also remove the nested hardware map as well since Terraform would need additional logic to understand the inner information.

tfvars:

```
example_users = {
  name1 = {
    cpus   = 8
    memory = 10
  }
  name2 = {
    cpus   = 9
    memory = 8
  }
}
```

main.tf:

```
for_each = var.example_users 
cpus = each.value["cpus"]
memory = each.value["memory"]
```

Comment: how about i define a map with variable name as "users" so my code would look something like this -

variable "users" {
type = map(object({
hardware = object({
cpus = number
memory = number
})
}))

and than add the default block to pass the user details for eg-

default = { name1 = {
hardware = {
cpus =1
memory =2 
}
},

user2 .........
and so on